# Smarty - How to store part of string from url to variable?

Tags: php, html, smarty

I don't know and I can't find on the internet how to store result of function explode to variable. What I am doing wrong ? REQUEST_URI is: /cz/cs/15_test.html . 15_test.html is what I need store in my variable. Thank you very much for help.

SMARTY:

```
{assign var="url_catname" value=explode("/",$smarty.server.REQUEST_URI)}
{assign var="url_catname" value=$url_catname[3]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot call PHP functions from Smarty like this. Do the assignment from the PHP code:

```
$smarty = new Smarty();
$pieces = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$smarty->assign('url_catname', $pieces[3]);
$smarty->display('blah-blah.tpl');
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is not completely true. You can call PHP functions but of course often it's more reasonable to do many things in PHP script and in Smarty just display the result.

When running:

```
{assign var="url_catname" value=explode("/",'/cz/cs/15_test.html')}
{assign var="url_catname" value=$url_catname[3]}
{$url_catname}
```

As output you receive:

> 15_test.html

so it seems to work without a problem (of course the same when you use `$smarty.server.REQUEST_URI`).

Exactly same effect you will get when using `explode` this way:

```
{assign var="url_catname" value="/"|explode:'/cz/cs/15_test.html'}
{assign var="url_catname" value=$url_catname[3]}
{$url_catname}
```

As output you receive:

> 15_test.html